# Find only those ID's where color are same on all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
id  color
1   Yellow
1   Pink
2   Yellow
2   blue
3   Yellow
3   Yellow
4   Red
```

Want only those ID's where color are same for all rows.

Have tried multiple way but didn't get any answer.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.ID,A.COLOR ORDER BY A.ID,A.COLOR)RNO,A.ID,A.COLOR from COLOR a join COLOR b on a.id = b.id and a.color=b.color
)
SELECT DISTINCT ID, COLOR FROM CTE --WHERE RNO > 1

SELECT *
FROM color a join (
    SELECT id, color, count(*) as qty
    FROM color
    GROUP BY id, color
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) b on a.id = b.id and a.color = b.color


select * from (
Select color,id,count(1)cnt from COLOR
group by color,id
having count(1) = 1

union all

Select color,id,count(1)cnt from COLOR
group by color,id
having count(1) > 1

) as t  where cnt  between 1 and 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` with `HAVING` will do the job. `COUNT(DISTINCT color)` will return distinct colors in each group, If it returns 1, then we have one color for all rows in a group.

```
select id from my_table
group by id
having count(distinct color) = 1
```

Comment: @RanjayKumar Then you should accept the answer (green check on the left) and optionally upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select c.*
from color c
where not exists (select 1 from color c1 where c1.id = c.id and c1.color <> c.color);
```